# CompanyHome reference in java API

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-enterprise

I have a scheduler  job configured  and created an action class by extending org.quartz.StatefulJob

In execute method of Action Class (Shown below) ,  What would be the best way to get reference to  CompanyHome in execute method ?

My  objctive to create a file in company home directory , when the action invoke.  Any suggesion ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe [follow a similar approach to how the Tags update scheduled job](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-repository/blob/ac38ac94ff4f9cbdf2671a9517781bda389a13c4/src/main/java/org/alfresco/repo/tagging/UpdateTagScopesQuartzJob.java) works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please implement a method like this

```
public NodeRef getCompanyHomeNodeReference() {
        NodeRef companyHomeNodeRef = null;
        companyHomeNodeRef = (NodeRef)AuthenticationUtil.runAsSystem(new AuthenticationUtil.RunAsWork<Object>() {
            public Object doWork() throws Exception {
                StoreRef storeRef = new StoreRef(StoreRef.PROTOCOL_WORKSPACE, "SpacesStore"));
                ResultSet rs = serviceRegistry.getSearchService().query(storeRef, SearchService.LANGUAGE_XPATH,
                        "/app:company_home"); 
                Object companyHome = null;
                try {
                    if (rs.length() == 0) {
                        LOG.error("Didn't find Company Home ");
                        throw new AlfrescoRuntimeException("Didn't find Company Home");
                    }
                    final NodeRef companyHomeNodeRef1 = rs.getNodeRef(0);
                    if(companyHomeNodeRef1 == null) {
                        LOG.info("Didn't find Company Homes");
                    }else {
                        companyHome = companyHomeNodeRef1;
                    }
                } finally {
                    rs.close();
                }
                return companyHome;
            }

        });
        return companyHomeNodeRef;
    }
```

import as below:

```
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.search.SearchService;
import org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.StoreRef;
```

please see how the critical code is placed in AuthenticationUtil (this is very important).

And then use below code to create a file:

```
fileFolderService.create(companyNodeRef, "yourfilename", ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT);
```

Add this bean in service-context.xml

```
<bean id="yourObj" class="MoveMonthlyDataAction">
        <property name="serviceRegistry">
            <ref bean="ServiceRegistry" />
        </property> 
</bean>
```

and mention in `MoveMonthlyDataAction  . java` as below,

```
public class MoveMonthlyDataAction {
    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    public void execute(){
        // your code
    }
    // getter and setter
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: thanks a lot for this code , just wondering how do  i get reference of ;serviceRegistry'

Comment: I am using plain java class and extending the Quartz , 'StatefulJob' to implement execute method. How can i have refernce of  'serviceRegistry' there .

Comment: @BrijeshNK i have edited the answer : how to autowire service registry in action class

Comment: Please refer this 
https://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/actions/tutorial/tutorial.html

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using `NodeLocatorService`?
https://docs.alfresco.com/4.0/concepts/node-locator-available.html.
For example:

```
NodeRef companyHomeNodeRef = registry.getNodeLocatorService().getNode(CompanyHomeNodeLocator.NAME, null, null);
```